# linux commands that read specific parts of files

Tags: linux

I'm having some troubles with homework questions for an intro linux class I am taking. Two questions in particular are really throwing me for a loop. I don't know what commands to use to list off specific parts of specific lines all in one command. This is the first time I've used linux and none of it was covered in lecture. Here are a few of the questions. I don't want the answers, just somewhere to start with the commands.

(1 command : ½ pt) You should be in your home directory. 
Create a file named summer-school in your home directory that contains the file names and lines (the data, not the line numbers) in those files where students scored less than ten out of a hundred.

The files look like this:

```
mary;:;79/100;st407
mary;:;51/100;m395
mary;:;71/100;cs541
mary;:;75/100;ph535
mary;:;77/100;ws420
mary;:;97/100;c392
mary;:;79/100;st638
mary;:;82/100;ar523
```

(2 commands : 1 pt) You should be in the ~cs155/pub/hw2Files/ directory.
(Do not add this change of directory command to your list of commands) 
Create a file named classes in your home directory with a list of all the classes taken by anyone. 
Uses the same type of files.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Two commands points more at `cut` and `sort -u`, I’d guess. But seriously, Izzytools, you do need to show us what you tried and what did and did not work.

Comment: Not getting your requirement!! can you elaborate it more OR what you have tried yet?

Comment: Could you solve this or still having the issue? I hope you could!